# Eigenvalues of VAR(1) coefficient matrix

Tags: vector-autoregression, eigenvalues

Suppose we have a VAR(1) model:

$$
\mathbf{X}_t = \boldsymbol{\Phi} \mathbf{X}_{t-1} + \mathbf{Z}_t, \hspace{10mm} \mathbf{Z}_t \sim WN(0,\Sigma)
$$

If we can keep plugging that equation into itself, we get

$$
\mathbf{X}_t = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \boldsymbol{\Phi}^j Z_{t-j} \tag{2}
$$

**as long as the eigenvalues of $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ have a modulus of less than $1$.**

[This textbook](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-29854-2?source=shoppingads&locale=en-us&gclid=CjwKCAjw67ajBhAVEiwA2g_jEKf_1qiyDaEgxdLOytGHj8Jz8C3igzcpeydVnSsFLdMLszCbcqYSgRoCkKQQAvD_BwE) mentions that this condition in bold is sufficient to guarantee that "the coefficients $\boldsymbol{\Phi}^j$ are absolutely summable." I assume the book really means "matrices with absolutely summable components" and uses "coefficients" to mean elements of the matrix, not the matrix itself.

In other words, I am thinking
$$
\sum_{j=0}^\infty |\left[\boldsymbol{\Phi}^j\right]_{kl}| < \infty \tag{1}
$$
I understand how this implies that each **component** of the [vector] $\sum_{j=0}^n \boldsymbol{\Phi}^j \mathbf{Z}_{t−j}$
converges in the mean square sense.

**My question is why is (1) a consequence of the eigenvalues being between $-1$ and $1$?**

---

The way I think about it appears to be incomplete. I suppose that $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$ is diagonalizable, so
$$
\boldsymbol{\Phi}^k = \mathbf{P} \boldsymbol{\Lambda}^k \mathbf{P}^{-1}
$$
where $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}$ is the diagonal matrix of eigenvalues, and $\mathbf{P}$ is an *invertible* matrix of eigenvectors arranged as columns. In this case,
$$
\boldsymbol{\Phi}^j \mathbf{Z}_{t−j} = \mathbf{P} \boldsymbol{\Lambda}^k \mathbf{P}^{-1} \mathbf{Z}_{t−j}
$$
and the right hand side goes to $0$ elementwise because $\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^k \mathbf{P}^{-1} \mathbf{Z}_{t−j}$ goes to $0$ by virtue of the fact that every element in
$\boldsymbol{\Lambda}^k$ vanishes.

Notice that my intuition a.) assumes diagonalization is possible, and b.) that it doesn't have anything to do with the individual components of the *matrix* of a power of $\boldsymbol{\Phi}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The eigenvalues of $\Phi^\intercal \Phi$ are the eigenvalues of $\Phi$ squared, and so also have moduli less than $1$. Proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2970893/22255)
2. For square $\Phi$, $\begin{Vmatrix} \cdot \end{Vmatrix}_2$ is a submultiplicative norm and
   $$
   \begin{Vmatrix} \Phi \end{Vmatrix}_2 = \sqrt{\max \{|\lambda| : \lambda \text{ is an eigenvalue of }\Phi^\intercal \Phi\}} := c
   $$
   Proof [here](https://www.math.drexel.edu/%7Efoucart/TeachingFiles/F12/M504Lect6.pdf)
3. $\| \sum_{k=0}^n \Phi^k \|_2 \le \sum_{k=0}^n \|\Phi\|_2^k \le \frac{1}{1 - c} < \infty$ so $\left[\sum_{k=0}^n \Phi^k\right]$ is invertible and in particular has finite elements. Proof is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/989971/22255)